# libopenal.so missing

Tags: apt, software-installation

I am trying to play Openspades here, it gives me this error.

```
Failed to dlload libopenal.so is missing in /home/user/openspades/openspades.mk/bin//libopenal.so. Cannot Open shared file: No such file or directory.
```

I checked if it could be installed by `apt-cache search` and was called libopenal1. and it is installed ALREADY. I tried the linking solution but seems like there's no such file with the name libopenal.* in the whole `/usr/lib/` file

Comment: The library is at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenal.so.1`. Did you compile the program yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making a soft link like this: `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenal.so.1 /home/user/openspades/openspades.mk/bin/libopenal.so`

To find installed versions, use `locate libopenal.so`. If some error about a database comes, create the database with `sudo updatedb`